# (Javascript) My if statement is acting like the conditions are true every time I run the code

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
let x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1))
console.log(x)

if (x = 6)
console.log('that was a 1/6 chance')
```

The code is intended to print "that was a 1/6 chance" whenever I run the program and x (the variable storing the random number) is 6. My actual result is the code saying "that was a 1/6 chance" whenever the code runs, which is technically true, but not my intended result.

Comment: should be `if (x == 6)`, one `=` is for *assignment*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the if condition to

> if (x == 6)

Your code will be like this:

> let x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)) console.log(x)
>
> if (x == 6) console.log('that was a 1/6 chance')

Notice the **==** in the if condition, what you are doing an assignment not comparing them. So assigning 6 to x will always be truthy hence running all the time.

Visit here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment

Answer (score 0):

`x=6` is an assignment, so actually *sets* `x` to `6`, you need to use `x===6` to check for equality